# Safari Giving Error for ** Operator

Tags: javascript, iphone, safari, swiper.js

I'm using the [Swiper](http://idangero.us/swiper/) plugin on my site and everything seem to be good except on Safari and iphone. On the iphone the video does not play automatically regardless of browser. And on MAC/Desktop the plugin doesn't load properly.

I'm suspecting it might have something to do with this error I'm getting when i go to the console log:

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token '*'`

It doesn't seem to recognize this operator **

the code:

`if (params.resistance) data$$1.currentTranslate = swiper.minTranslate() - 1 + (-swiper.minTranslate() + data$$1.startTranslate + diff) ** resistance` (! Unexpected Token)

Comment: Not sure what a `?` means but MDN docs has a `?` under Safari and iOS Safari for the exponentiation (**) operator compatibility. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Exponentiation

Comment: Hmm base on the link you sent me. that is confusing.. I assume even they don't know if Safari accept `**` operator. I wonder how I would go about fixing this issue..

Comment: You can use Math.Pow() instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MDN says this about the exponentiation operator- "This is an experimental API that should not be used in production code." The reason for this is probably due to it [not being compatible in some/all browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Browser_compatibility) (including IE, edge, Edge mobile, safari, and iOS Safari).

You can substitute with [Math.pow()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow). At the bottom of this doc you will see in the **See Also** that exponentiation operator has a experimentation icon next to it.

Comment: ahh I see, guess I'll go through it and replace what I can. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Including what @Andrew Lohr said I found a nifty plugin for having video [play on iPhone](https://github.com/bfred-it/iphone-inline-video) too.